# Android - Scary permission to know when the phone rings

Tags: android, android-permissions, incoming-call

I want my app to know when the phone rings so I added the following permission as requested:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

But when installing it on my device for testing, it says "Read phone state and identity" - now you tell me, what user will want to confirm this permission (for a non identity related app)? :) I only want to know if/when the phone rings but the user might think I'm after his identity and won't install it. What is your experience with this? Any way around this?

I'm using a BroadcastReceiver for that:

```
<receiver android:name="CheckIncomingNumber">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and

```
public class CheckIncomingNumber extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (!state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            return;
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Utils.logToFile("incoming number: " + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: "_Any way around this?_" No.

Comment: The reason for the terminology is that `READ_PHONE_STATE` also allows you to access the IMEI and IMSI values (on GSM devices, and presumably their equivalents on CDMA devices). There are already dozens, perhaps hundreds, of permissions, but they do not allow for arbitrary granularity. You might consider editing your question to explain why you "want [your] app to know when the phone rings" and what you plan to do at that time, along with how you are implementing this today. You are unlikely to get "any way around this" without that level of detail, so somebody can suggest an alternative.

Comment: Funny, my question is how to lower the level of intrusion I have over the phone because I don't need that much of intrusion and still you asked a question as if my intentions are bad  :) Anyway, the user selects different contacts that the app will do something for them when they call, so I need to know if the incoming phone number is one of the selected phone numbers. At the moment I do nothing but logging those numbers because I'm still in development stage and I want to see what do I get in such cases.

Comment: Your users are afraid of everything! All permissions do scare them, since I saw another question of yours regarding the READ/WRITE permissions...

Comment: This permission is yet to scare users because it's still in development stage, I was wondering if I could prevent it because I don't need that much of intrusion. Regarding my other post: @CommonsWare gave a wonderful reply on how to prevent that one, I hope I'll have a way for this permission as well. I'm a newbie so I do all this in order to learn as much as I can.

Comment: @Amos: Please use the @ notation when replying to comments, so everyone knows who the reply is directed towards and so the commenter is notified. "still you asked a question as if my intentions are bad" -- no, I asked a question as if your intentions are unclear. A "workaround" implies a set of requirements, and we need to know those. A "workaround" for gravity depends a lot on whether you are trying to paint a ceiling or launch a spacecraft.

Comment: @Amos: "I need to know if the incoming phone number is one of the selected phone numbers" -- I presume you are using a `PhoneStateListener` for that, which AFAIK does require `READ_PHONE_STATE`. I am unaware of any means to find out the incoming phone number that does not involve either `READ_PHONE_STATE` or `READ_CONTACTS`, and even the latter wouldn't necessarily be in real time (e.g,. monitoring the `CallLog` `ContentProvider`).

Comment: Actually I'm using a BroadcastReceiver, please see my updated post. READ_CONTACT is relevant to what the app is doing so there is nothing to be "scared" of. I was wondering if there is a less intrusive permission for just knowing when a phone is ringing. I guess there isn't.

Comment: why don't you explain why did you need the permission in your app's description. And if your app have any added value for the user, then the user wold definitely consider your case. Technically Mr. @CommonsWare is more than 1OO% correct

Comment: If I won't have a choice, I will explain hoping users will believe me (someone they don't know)

Comment: @Amos, as I understood from your primary description of problem & comments, your app is somewhat contact related. So your permission is quite relevant. Don't be tensed that much.

Comment: I was referring to the identity part of the permission while the name of the permission is only read phone state. I can explain read phone state because it is relevant to the app but not identity which comes along with this permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TelephonyManager.listen(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int)) with flag [PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_CALL_STATE) which does not require permissions.